# Is there a way to tell typescript if an array is passed in I want an array returned

Tags: arrays, typescript

The typescript code below shows an type error when assigning to `result` from `getName(personA)` as well as a type error when assigning `[nameA, nameB]` via the `getName([personA, personB])` call.

This is despite the fact that when `getName()` receives an object input, the return value is a string and when the `getName` call receives an array of objects input, the return value is always and array. Due to the `Array.isArray(data)` check.

```
const personA = {
    name: "person A"
}

const personB = {
    name: "person B"
}

function getName(data: object | object[]): string | string[] {
    if (Array.isArray(data)) { 
        return data.map(extractName)
    } else {
        return extractName(data)
    }
}

function extractName(object): string {
    return object.name
}

// shows a type error 
const result: string = getName(personA)

// shows type error
const [nameA, nameB] = getName([personA, personB])
```

Is there anyway to teach typescript that `const result: string = getName(personA)` and `const [nameA, nameB] = getName([personA, personB])` should not show a type error? Maybe some type of Generics magic?

You can quickly replicate the error in the typescript playground with the code above.
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html

Comment: I don't think you can type this correctly yet, but in 2.8 should be able to do this with conditional types https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/21316

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You strictly set `string` type for `result` variable, but `getName` returns `string | string[]` and its not assignable to `string`. You need overload `getName` function with `string` and `string[]` arguments like

```
function getName(data: object): string;
function getName(data: object[]): string[];
function getName(data: object | object[]): string | string[] {
  if (Array.isArray(data)) {
    return data.map(extractName);
  } else {
    return extractName(data);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Overloads! Exactly what I needed.

For some reason the 
`function getName(data: object[]): string[];` overload needs to be above
`function getName(data: object): string;`